# Can a knowledge check be used to identify the powers of a unique named enemy?

Tags: dnd-4e, knowledge-check

In Encounter 29: Arena of Kord in Madness at Gardmore Abbey the players face an enemy leader called:

```
Leralix, Minotaur Magus (L) Level 9 Controller (Leader)
```

Because Leralix is a unique named monster, I don't see how knowledge about a group of monsters, in this case minotaurs, would really help identify the powers of a unique boss.

What is the official ruling on knowledge checking the powers of unique monsters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure! Just because it's unique doesn't mean the party doesn't have a chance to know something about it that they've picked up through their adventures. Each creature in the Monster Manuals has such information, even the unique ones.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no official ruling for reputation.  What I might recommend is a Knowledge(Local) check as a base and the more they succeed by, the more they know.  It could be as limited as knowing the race and hinting at the class abilities he has and thus giving the players a minimum class & level, all the way up to that Nat20 roll of finding that grizzled (barely) survivor who knows an ace up his sleeve.

Comment: No such thing as Knowledge (Local) in 4E. Cloest thing would be History or Streetwise.