# What type of action is a knowledge check?

Tags: dnd-4e, knowledge-check

Based on a [recent question about knowledge checks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13569/can-a-knowledge-check-be-used-to-identify-the-powers-of-a-unique-named-enemy), I started wondering what kind of action Knowledge Checks were. The compendium doesn't seem to state it for monster knowledge checks (but, e.g. detect magic checks are a standard action). Are they Free, Minor, or Standard actions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No action is required**

From the *Rules Compendium* pg 130.

> **Action**: No action.
>
> A character either knows or doesn't know the information.

Comment: gah, this information is noticeably absent from the online compendium :(

Comment: @waxeagle - several bits are, hence why I carry my RC most everywhere :)

Comment: They do want you to buy that Compendium, after all. ;)